# Remove Spring data rest self link templating in projections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "patient" : {
      "firstName" : "Kidus",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/api/patients/2{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
    }
}
```

As you can see i have an embedded entity(patient). It returns all the data including link to the entity but the link is templated. I'm not using a front-end HATEOAS client and i don't plan on changing course on that. So i would need a normal non-templated link. Is there any non-hacky way to achieve this?

Comment: If you use Spring HATEOAS and define a projection on a resource class, the self link will be templated. It's a convention enforced by Spring, so there is no "non-hacky" way to change that (but there probably is a hacky one).

Answer (score 0):

You can force the template to be expanded in this way:

```
@GetMapping("/myresources/{id}")
public EntityModel<MyResource> myResource(String id) {

    MyResource resource = ...;
    return new EntityModel<>(
                  resource,
                  linkTo(methodOn(getClass()).myResource(id)).withSelfRel().expand(id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `self` link by using a custom [`RepresentationModelProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/server/RepresentationModelProcessor.html):

```java
@Component
public class MyProjectionProcessor implements RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<MyProjection>> {

    private static final Pattern TEMPLATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\{\\?.*");

    @Override
    public EntityModel<MyProjection> process(final EntityModel<MyProjection> model) {
        // copy the model without links
        final EntityModel<MyProjection> newModel = EntityModel.of(model.getContent());
        // loop over links
        for (final Link link : model.getLinks()) {
            Link newLink = link;
            // replace self link if it is templated
            if (link.hasRel(IanaLinkRelations.SELF) && link.isTemplated()) {
                final String href = TEMPLATE_PATTERN.matcher(link.getHref()).replaceFirst("");
                newLink = Link.of(href, IanaLinkRelations.SELF);
            }
            newModel.add(newLink);
        }
        return newModel;
    }

}
```